# Why UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME set to null instead of PRIMARY when adding foreign key from a specific table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I get a mysterious one here for me;

It started with getting an 
`Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`
on inserting a new row in `table_A`, that contains the foreign key.

After investigating, I found that when I'm creating a new relation from `referenced_table` to an other table (like `table_A`) the field UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME in table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS set to null instead of PRIMARY like all others relations I'm creating.

I dug and compared `referenced_table` with many others with same relations and working normally, an just didn't find anything to hit on.

Have anybody, have any hints for me in going further in that amazing journey? :)

Other informations:

- I'm using MysqlWorkbench 6.3
- I'm using MySQL 5.7.15
- I'm on OSX El
  Capitan (Got the same error on test server running Ubuntu)
- Relations tested are one-to-many

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the referenced table (last column in `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`) exist? I mean the actual table (`select * from that_table`), not the value in `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`.

Comment: Yes, the referenced table exist in REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS and "physically" too. `SELECT * FROM referenced_table` return de 56k+ rows.

Comment: Just to make sure: I assume you have checked that the value you want to insert to `tableB` is really in `tableA`. It sounds to me like the required index on `tableA` is missing.  I would try the following: use the result of `show create table tableA` and replace the tablename with `tableA_dummy` and execute it. If the table can be created, it looks fine. If not, you might have to add the result of `show create table tableA` and B to your question so we can check.

Comment: Yes I confirm, the value on table A is in table B.  On creation of the tableA_dummy I got this error: `Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table 'tableA_dummy'`.
Thanks a lot!! :)
I'll dig in that and come up tomorrow with more details.

Comment: Ah, this might be my mistake, I was too short. If you have named key constraints, you have to give them a different name too, because they have to be unique in the whole database, so this might not be the problem that caused your original error.

Comment: Shame on me; obviously the key is duplicated since I copy-paste the query from `show create`...  Back to square one.

Comment: But, I got an error!! :) 
`Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: Yes, that is the expected error in this case, though it can have several reasons (wrong type, dropped index, wrong name, ...), but you probably just dropped the index in `tableA`. Check (or add) the `show create table ...`, you can probably just add the missing index again to `tableB`. Repeat it until `tableA_dummy` works, then drop and add the foreign key to `tableA` again.

Comment: I resolved it finally. The table had it's engine set to MyISAM (for unknown raisons)  (thanks to the "show create..." ) and all others were innoDB. So it made me curious about that, and push me to try a test on local database: I change it to innoDB and since then everything goes as expected! :)

Thanks to everybody, you helped me to figured out.